# Python Tkinter Event Binding

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling

I am playing around with Python Tkinter, and Event Binding does not work in my script. Here is my script:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def quit():
    exit(0)

class ChartApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}
        # This is not an error to have 2 StartPage. I am planning to implement multiple pages afterwards
        for F in (StartPage, StartPage):
            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        def printsomething(msg):
            print(msg + " is selected!")

        pg1_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1", command=lambda: printsomething("Page 1"))
        pg1_button.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky='e')

        pg2_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2", command=lambda: printsomething("Page 2"))
        pg2_button.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10, sticky='w')

        self.bind("a", lambda event: self.focus_set())
        self.bind("a", printsomething("Page 1"))

app = ChartApp()
app.mainloop()
```

I want to press button "a" on my keyboard as if I click on `pg1_buttion` to execute the `printsomething` function. However, it does not work. Also, once I run my script, I have the following output automatically.

```
Output:
Page 1 is selected!
Page 1 is selected!
```

I am sure the auto output is related to these 2 lines but I don't know why

```
self.bind("a", lambda event: self.focus_set())
self.bind("a", printsomething("Page 1"))
```

Another question, I have a menu bar File -> Exit. I want to press the button "f" then "e" to exit the GUI. I tried accelerator option in 'filemenu.add_command' but it does not work. 
So what can I try next? Thank you!

Comment: That’s an awful lot of code. Please try to reduce it down to a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the displayed frame does not have focus. I tried adding `focus_set` to the `show_frame()` method and that seems to work.

```
def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
    frame.focus_set()
```

But maybe you should bind events to the root window instead.

Also, it looks like you are trying to bind the key "a" to more than one callback. You can do this but it's a little more complicated:

```
self.bind("a", first_callback)
self.bind("a", second_callback, "+")   # Add callback
```

The "+" at the end makes bind understand that it should not substitute the first_callback but to ADD the second_callback.

Comment: I added `frame.focus_set()` in `show_frame()` but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: I tried with your method again and also need to edit the line to `self.bind("a", lambda x: printsomething("Page 1"))` for the pressing of "a" to work. Not sure why thought. But thank you!